# Magento show elements collection by ID

Tags: magento-1.9, php

How Can I show elemnets by ID

```
 $collection = Mage::getModel('storelocator/stores')->getCollection();

    foreach($collection as $store){
        echo $store->getStreet();
        echo $store->getPostal_code();
        echo $store->getTitle();

    }
```

I tried  `$collection = Mage::getModel('storelocator/stores')->load($currentId);` but is not work

Comment: What do you mean with `by ID`? Your question is quite unclear

Answer (score 1):

I find it is

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('storelocator/stores')->load($currentId);
        echo $collection->getTitle().'<br>';
        echo $collection->getStreet().'<br>';
        echo $collection->getCity().' '.$collection->getPostal_code();
```